# How to test single test modules in intellij in maven project having test dependency?

Tags: maven, testing, intellij-idea

Here is the situation :

I have 2 modules, module KID that depends on module PARENT.
I have a test class in PARENT that can be used in KID to test the implementation of a class.

To do so, I added a the following dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>PARENT</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

With maven, the tests are running fine.

With Intellij, (right click on the java test folder + run 'All tests' for KID), I get a NoClassDefFoundError. The problem is that tests from both modules are running, but it is only using the dependencies of the kid.

In the project PARENT I have a dependency that I don't need in KID :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Setting the scopes to provided instead of test will fix my problem, but it allow the main code to use test code.

I might have missed something ? This is a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer there : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112978

That's because a run configuration is created by template.
And that template has default setting to pick classes across module dependencies.

For me in 132.46 the following helps:
1. Open Run Configuration dialog, Defaults section.
2. Find respective template. I tried JUnit.
3. "Test kind" combo, select All in package.
4. Set "In single module".
5. Apply to save the template.

After that delete created configurations and repeat "Run All tests". It picks only classes from current module for me.

The possible improvement in IDEA is to modify these defaults specially for Maven-based projects. Rather specific change...